# About (regularity) tag for PDEs

Tags: discussion, tagging

Quite recently a tag called [regularity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularity) has been created. The [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/regularity/info) says:

> The concept of regularity concerns the smoothness of weak solutions to a partial differential equations.

At the moment the tag contains 4 questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893177/interior-h2-regularity-applying-cauchys-inequality-with-epsilon), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893224/interior-h2-regularity-inequalities-over-regions-u-and-w-subset-u), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893336/interior-h2-regularity-using-a-textbooks-identity-to-show-an-important-est), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893539/higher-interior-regularity), all of them are about PDEs.

However there are many notions in mathematics, which has the words [regular/regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity#Mathematics) in the name.

Should this tag be renamed to indicate somehow that it is related to PDEs? (For example, [regularity-pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularity-pde).)

It would be also good to hear from people who know more about [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde)s whether this tag is potentially useful.

Comment: I should probably also mentioned that I [pinged](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893177/interior-h2-regularity-applying-cauchys-inequality-with-epsilon#comment1864768_893177) the user, who created this tag, about this post.

Comment: I hope I am not too [presumptuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/pde/topusers) in answering your question. `:-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have changed the name to [regularity-theory-of-pdes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularity-theory-of-pdes) which just barely fit the character number limit.

Regularity theory is traditionally one of the three main foci of the studies of PDEs, the other two are the existence and the uniqueness of solutions. (This is especially the case from questions arising from calculus of variations.) So I think it is not horrible to have such a tag. Though I am sure there are many existing questions that can be tagged as such.

And I agree: regularity is too common a word to be monopolized by PDE questions.